# I want to integrate google calendar in my app , so that all my team mates can add event and all event should be public within the members of the app

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I want to integrate google calendar in my app , so that all my team mates can add event and all event should be public within the members of the app

```
final ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
event.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, calendarId);

event.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, name);
event.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, millisstarttime);
event.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, millisendtime);
event.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, venue);
event.put(CalendarContract.Events.ALL_DAY, 0);   // 0 for false, 1 for true
event.put(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM, 1);
event.put(CalendarContract.Events.ACCESS_LEVEL, CalendarContract.Events.ACCESS_PRIVATE);
event.put(CalendarContract.Events.AVAILABILITY, CalendarContract.Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY);// 0 for false, 1 for true

String timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault().getID();
event.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, timeZone);

this.getContentResolver().insert(baseUri, event);
```

Comment: Please see the documentation for sharing the events with your contacts: https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/sharing

Comment: You have to find the identities of your contacts using: https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people